# How to display the Horizantal Access value from dataset field in rdlc report line chart

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, rdlc

what property need to set the for the displaying this value in line chart in Rdlc report[image]

Want to display right side capacity column value in line chart

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have specified interval and also the minimum and maximum limits so remove all those or set it to auto and it will come
Just try it

Comment: It should have worked, you try disabling  autofit property and also rotate horizontal axis 90 in horizontal axis property, It can also be the problem due to space

Answer (score 0):

It's just configuration to show data in horizontal axis.

1) Goto rdlc-chart right  on horizontal axis property click.

2) Goto Number tab.

3) Custom category -> click on custom formats (Fx).

4) Click on "fields" on category portion.

5) Click on databases field which one show as horizontal axis.